# Can I prevent class definition unless a method is implemented?

Tags: python, plugins, abstract-class

I'm trying to figure out how to provide a base class to plugin writers so that they provide definitions for several static methods.

A plugin class is a collection of static methods which will never be instantiated.

I know how to use ABC to prevent *instantiation* of a class missing method implementations, which will not provide the safety I would like. Is there a pattern to prevent *definition*?

Comment: Probably, but why bother? It’ll likely prevent missing implementations from being assigned later, and a whole host of other things that are inevitably used in Python.

Comment: I certainly hope not. Python is supposed to be a "consenting adults" language, not a sandbox.

Comment: Is there a better approach to assisting plugin writers, who may not be very tech-savvy?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by writing your own metaclass similar to ABCMeta, which checks for abstract methods at class-definition time and raises an error if it finds any.  Here's an example:

```
class ClassABC(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        abstracts = set()
        for base in bases:
            abstracts.update(getattr(base, '__abstractclassmethods__', set()))
        for abstract in abstracts:
            if getattr(getattr(cls, abstract), '__isabstractmethod__', False):
                raise TypeError("Your class doesn't define {0}".format(abstract))
        for attr in attrs:
            if getattr(attrs[attr], '__isabstractmethod__', False):
                abstracts.add(attr)
        cls.__abstractclassmethods__ = abstracts

class BaseClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ClassABC

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        print("I am base foo")
```

Then:

```
>>> class Derived(BaseClass):
...     pass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    class Derived(BaseClass):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 8, in __init__
    raise TypeError("Your class doesn't define {0}".format(abstract))
TypeError: Your class doesn't define foo
```

My example is fairly quick and dirty and only scantily tested, and you might want to refine it to check various sorts of edge cases.  What I did is I raised the error if there is an abstract method that wasn't defined in the currently-being-defined class.  (Otherwise an error would be raised because the abstract base class doesn't define concrete implementations of its own abstract methods.)